# one to one with two embeddable and diffrent key name hibernate

Tags: hibernate, jpa, one-to-one

I have two tables,

Each table have two key fields

The field key names are different between the two tables

How to tie them with @OneToOne annotation

```
class a {

@EmbeddedId
private Apk id

}

class b{

@EmbeddedId
private Bpk id;

}

@Embeddable
class Apk{

aa;
aaa; 

}

@Embeddable
class Bpk{

bb;
bbb;

}


aa= bb && bb = bbb
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, this should work for you.
Make sure that both `APK` and `BPK` implement `Serializable` and have proper `equals` and `hashCode` override.

```
class A {

    @EmbeddedId
    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumns({
        @JoinColumn(name = "aa", referencedColumnName = "bb"),
        @JoinColumn(name = "aaa", referencedColumnName = "bbb")
    })
    private APK aID;

}

class B {

    @EmbeddedId
    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "aID")
    private BPK bID;

}
```